# Flag On Closed Post Remains Pending

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history

Years ago, I have flagged this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447936/using-php-cakephp-for-a-payment-gateway/5447955#5447955 post, and the flag is still shown as pending.

I have found and read a lot of seemingly related QAs here on meta-SO, but could not find a fitting post. I know now that *the pending flags queue is best left alone most of the time, as it will be dealt with eventually*.

However, I am not sure, if this suggested course of action is sound in this case, as it could hint at a possibility to optimize a meta workflow.

Wouldn't it make sense for a moderator closing a post to review its related pending flags during the closing process?

Comment: what did you flag it as? also note that the *question* is closed, and you claim to have flagged the *answer*.  They're two different *posts*.

Comment: You're asking that Jeff Atwood personally handles your flag?

Comment: @TZHX, nice catch. It has been multiple years now, iirc I just had the facility to raise a flag and provide a short text.

Comment: It is not possible to "close" an answer.  As usual, a bad question was responsible for a bad answer.   The offending phrase was already edited out of the post by the time the moderator got to it so there wasn't much for him to do.  He decided to close the question instead.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant.

Comment: Still should have dismissed the flag if he did so ...

Comment: Strangely - there's not an actual flag pending (although it shows as pending in your history) - so there's nothing for a moderator to "clear". The question's deleted, which didn't affect anything, so I un-deleted, then re-deleted the answer you're referring to, which also didn't do anything. I've pinged a dev. - hopefully they'll have a look when they can. (I have a feeling that in 2011 the system was different and this is one of those weird transitional cases)

Comment: @JonClements, outstanding! Awesome that you have looked deeper into it.

Comment: Yeah... For years, we didn't have a resolution status for flags (pending/helpful/disputed/declined) - so old flags are marked handled, but without a "result". The flag summary page *used to* have a disclaimer noting this, but looks like that was dropped and all these old flags now show as pending - I'm looking into this... Update: looks like this bug's been in here for a while, although probably a bit more visible with the recent work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a check that should ensure old flags without a resolution status (but which *have* been resolved) are not taken into account as pending.

With you in the next build (rev 2015.12.9.3065, meta rev 2015.12.9.3959).