# Three flags from 2011 still show up as "waiting for review"

Tags: bug, flag-history

From the [flag history page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/660921?group=1&status=1):

[image]

As you can see, three flags from 2011 seem stuck as "pending"; they also don't show the "pending" badge. The number on the right is correct though.

Possibly related: [Flag On Closed Post Remains Pending](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312012/flag-on-closed-post-remains-pending)

Comment: Very old flags never used to record a status with them. There used to be a message on the right explaining that for users who had any such flags, but I guess it got removed with the new filter options. Would be curious if it's possible to exclude them from the filter. There's obviously a query that would work since it counts them correctly.

Comment: Allow flags to be handled in 6 to 8 years ...

Comment: @animuson Right, don't remember that ;-) It looks very confusing like this IMHO; can't you just put these flags in "helpful"?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Well the problem is we don't know if they were helpful or unhelpful. Since no status was ever recorded back then, it could have been a blatantly wrong flag or an extremely helpful flag - we don't want to just change them all to helpful as a solution. Removing them from the filters would be the best option.

Comment: @animuson Well, it seems to me that not a whole lot of people are going to care about 5 year old filters? I agree it's not "correct", but it *is* better UX. The "waiting for review" filter is one would actually want to look at ("helpful", not sure much I think)... But yeah, just removing or putting them in a "no status" filter would probably be even better.